# Currency convert using PayPal

Tags: paypal

I'm looking for a way to convert prices in my online store using PayPal's official rates.
I've googled and looked through PayPal's documentation but haven't find anything.

The currency converter when you log in has exactly the function I need.

Have anyone solved this or anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Classic API seems to support it: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ConvertCurrency_API_Operation/